# log-logistic regression model VS nonlinear regression in seed germination

Tags: r, regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear

*EDIT: I ran test again with data set provided and realized that the cause of problem is definitely rank deficiency, because estimated values of parameters in nonlinear regression showed non existing p values and there was no way to create confidence intervals with this data.

### Thank you all for reading and help! This question is closed.

I researched seed germination. I took 75 seed replicates and put them in  different ecological parameters (like temperature) and took data about sprouts in different time intervals.

Reading statistical science papers about this topic, I found that I should analyze my data in a time-to-event model (dose response curve), where I can use log-logistic regression or nonlinear regression (Ritz et al., 2013 -http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.eja.2012.10.003).

Two models (nonlinear and log-logistic) lead to quantitatively very similar fitted germination curves, i.e., similar parameter estimates, but qualitatively different statements about the precision of estimates. Nonlinear regression model yields an overly precise estimate of the proportion of seeds that germinated during the experiment, so the precision reported by the nonlinear regression is too high.

Similarly, the 95% confidence intervals of the fitted curves also demonstrate the dramatic difference in precision of the two models: Accurate prediction of germination percentages is not warranted by the data unless very low percentages are of interest.

Because of that I choose log-logistic regression as a model. First few data sets; treatments analyzed in R using analysis of Dose-Response Curves (drc package) went smooth, and I was able to plot and get final graph. Such data, which was successfully analyzed, contained treatments where max seeds germination was for example 50% of total seed number.

Example:

[image: Example of successful data analysis]

The problems arose when I entered the log-logistic model with treatment where all the seeds germinated in a short amount of time (meaning the treatment for this set of seeds is most adequate for their successful sprouting). For example, 100% of seeds germinated in only 5 days, so there are only two or three time intervals and a large number of sprouted seeds. The R program here reported  convergence error:

```
Error in optim(startVec, opfct, hessian = TRUE, method = optMethod, control = list(maxit = maxIt,  : 
non-finite value supplied by optim
Error in drmOpt(opfct, opdfct1, startVecSc, optMethod, constrained, warnVal,  : 
Convergence failed
```

Since I'm still a student in biology I have a very basic knowledge in statistics, so I tried to solve the problem with literature.

At first I thought that convergence failed because of perfect or complete separation, but through longer research it seems that the problem lies in rank deficiency.

When I analyzed the same data with nonlinear regression I've managed to fit curve and plot a graph without a problem.

So, is there a way to make log-logistic model work even though I have obviously small data in cases of 100% germination? Should I switch to nonlinear regression  even though the reported precision would be too high.

Comment: What does "perfect" mean in "gives standard errors which are almost perfect"? What does "almost perfect data" mean? Would you be able to avoid the ambiguous word "perfect" and actually explain what you mean each time instead? Could you do the same with the word "good"? (e.g. in "good confidence intervals").... similarly with the word "reliable" (what does reliable mean there?)  ... I really have trouble figuring out what you're saying with all those terms undefined.

Comment: Hi Glen! Thank you for your answer and questions. 
I realise that my use of words in describing the problem is quite ambigous. The fact that I'm trying to describe it that way is why I said that I'm not a statistician.

I'll try to explain these things more accurately as much my knowledge allows.

Comment: Dear Glen, I updated the whole question with more precise informations. Please read them and share your thoughts. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: I have edited this over small points of English, but I doubt I have made this much clearer to anyone statistical. The graph seems to show just 4 data points. Is this right? If so, you can't do much to tell which model is better.

Comment: Thank you for your time Nick Cox. Yes, the data set I have overall has small amount of data and I guess that is the cause of problems. The paper I gave above (Ritz, et. al. 2013) already made a research where they concluded the log-logistic model should be used in terms of seed germination, so that shouldn't be doubtful. The problem here is if there is any way to make log-logistic model work in described situation of rank deficiency.

Comment: The question is solved as a rank deficiency without help. Thank you all!

Comment: Alan -- you could post the explanation of what the problem was and how you figured out that was the issue as an answer instead of editing your question. If you really don't want people to answer your question at all, you're free to delete it, but it looks like a useful question and your solution may help others, so I'd encourage you to post a short discussion as an answer.